# How to change dbconsole connection port to oracle listener

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm a beginner of Oracle DB and I've got some trouble when running dbconsole, here is the problem:

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Product, and I've changed my listener port to be `11521`, not `1521` by default. Here is my network config file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: 
/usr1/oracle/product/11gR1/db/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
  (ORACLE_HOME=/usr1/oracle/product/11gR1/db)
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
  (SID_NAME = orcl)
 )
)
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 11521))
  )
```

When I trying to start dbcosole, it starts successfully but the web page says that cannot connect to oracle instance, and the connection info shows that dbconsole still try to connect instance by port `1521`.

So here is the question: how can I change dbconsole config to let it connect oracle listener by port `11521`? Thanks in advance~

Comment: Have you changed the port in the server? Changing it on the configuration only means that you are saying to your client to use that port not that the server will run on that port.

Comment: Glad to have your reply. I guess the server port has changed, I can see that port `11521` has been used by `tnslsnr` but port `1521` has not been used.